# Changing app timezone via service provider

Tags: php, laravel, timezone

I'm trying to make a package which can change the app timezone via the `.env` file.

In my `.env` file I have added the following line:

```
APP_TIMEZONE=America/Toronto
```

Now, in my package service provider class, I have the following in the `boot()` method:

```
\Log::info(config('app.timezone'));
config(['app.timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC)')]);
\Log::info(config('app.timezone'));
```

My log file confirms that the `app.timezone` has been changed from `UTC` to `America/Toronto`. However, when I insert a new record into the database, the `created_at` column still uses `UTC`.

Why is this happening? Working a local timezone in Laravel is becoming a nightmare.

Comment: Did you clear your config cache? just run php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to run `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: You're telling me I have to run this command inside of the `boot()` method for every single request?

Comment: No, just once after you switch your timezone.